# Does refactoring code affect Flutter app performance?

Tags: flutter, dart

If I split my code into multiple files and folders, does it the overall improve app performance ? Or is it just done to keep things readable and maintainable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using stateful and setState approach then if you don't split your code in to widgets then there is a high chance of rebuilding many unnecessary widgets and with splitting you can manage this issue way better...but if you are using any stateManagement then no it just makes it more readable